# Override UI element .enabled property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to override property of `UIView` class to do extra lines of code each time property value of .enabled is changed. How do I do that?

For example:

1. There is `MyUIView` class myClass
2. There is myClass.enabled property
3. I want to override this to add next things

   - Edit subview of type `UIView` and set background to red colour if enabled/green if disabled.
   - Edit subview of type `UIButton` and make it disabled if disabled/enabled if enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will look something like this -

```
    class SubClass: UIView {
        override var userInteractionEnabled: Bool {
            didSet {
                // Do the color change and other stuff. 
                // Use oldValue to access old value 
            }
        }
    }
```

There is much more to explore about this setter and getter.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. Thank you!